# Where is it? - The Google Earth Challenge Ep. 4

Tags: visual, geography

Yeh I still can't give out the first hint... Bring it on! :D

---

This puzzle will provide a screenshot in somewhere on Google Earth, please try your best to identify where the location is. The reasons to find out the location should be part of your answer.

Will give a zoom-out image as the next hint if not be answered yet for a while.

**Note:** It's not recommended to use Google Search by Image function directly(I'll try my best to avoid that when selecting the screenshot). **Try to use any feature on pixels or your geography knowledge to derive the location.**

---

**Question:**

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's

> the [Tenzing-Hillary airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenzing%E2%80%93Hillary_Airport), known as the most dangerous airport in the world.

See Google Maps:

> [image: screenshot of satellite view]

How I found this:

> the runway number is clearly either 06 or 90. [Runway numbers only go from 01 to 36](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/84), so it's 06, representing the heading. So it's got to be some airport with a runway on heading 06, presumably a famous or noteworthy one. Google autocomplete results for "runway 06" included Schiphol and Shannon airports, which I duly checked, but no joy. The other realisation is the unusual colouration on the image in the OP, which might suggest an airport in some extreme climate or unusual position. I checked Antarctica airport and then tried looking for *shortest* runways, which immediately gave me the right answer.

Comment: Well I still can't give out my first hint :P. Great derivations and efforts!

Answer (score 4):

So I hadn't realized that

> Runways were given numbers by their heading. So this is a runway facing 60 degrees (06/24 meaning 60/240 labelled for the two ends of the runway). Cleveland has one. But I'm sure there are many such runways. Maybe there's a list somewhere. Unless I'm totally off base here!

Comment: Yes a good start :D

Comment: Go and ask on [aviation.se] SE ;-)